# Gnome Metacity, extension how its works?

Tags: gnome, metacity

For any reason that I don't understand the extension installed in Gnome not appear in Gnome Metacity.
If I logged in Gnome Metacity and go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ is unavailable to me install any extension, and gnome-tweak-tool have no signal of the extension's tabs ,my gnome version is "GNOME Shell 3.14.4", Ubuntu "15.04", If any Information is needed please let me know.

#### Question:

Metacity can use extensions?, if yes, how I should activate?

Thanks,

Update:
In the xsession-error (Logged with metacity) have this:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for ibus started at run_im.
upstart: gnome-settings-daemon main process (2521) terminated with     status 1
upstart: gnome-session (GNOME) main process (2541) terminated with status 1
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in y our Gnome version > 3.14. They offer a link about this and how to override this problem, so I
Quoted from [I'm using GNOME 3. Why can't I install extensions?](https://extensions.gnome.org/about/#no-detection)

> If you are using GNOME 3.4 or newer and installation still doesn't
>   work, check to make sure that the "GNOME Shell Integration" plugin is
>   installed and enabled in your browser preferences. Some browsers have
>   a feature, click-to-play, which make it so the plugin cannot start
>   without user intervention. Make sure that either
>   http://extensions.gnome.org is whitelisted for the click-to-play
>   feature, or click-to-play is turned off entirely. Check your browser's
>   help for more details.
>
> If you are behind a proxy, make sure you have configured your proxy in
>   both your browser's configuration dialog as well as GNOME's Network
>   panel under System Settings. GNOME Shell Extensions needs both
>   settings panels configured for the one-click installation to work.
>
> Some distributions don't quite package GNOME correctly. Make sure that
>   you have the unzip package installed.
>
> If you have checked all of these solutions and are still having
>   trouble installing extensions, please file a bug report using the link
>   in the footer of the page, giving your GNOME version, distribution and
>   version, what solutions you have already tried, as well as what the
>   Looking Glass says in both the Extensions and Errors tabs. It's also
>   helpful to have a copy of the ~/.xsession-errors file from the session
>   that you installed extensions from.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand,  or maybe I wasn't clear enough,  I could install extension but only in Gnome, when i logged in metacity, they not appear.

Comment: What do you mean by "logged in metacity"? You can only use Gnome Extensions on Gnome Shell.

Comment: Ok, so gnome-metacity is not Gnome shell?

Comment: @xangua , Can you please explain me, Where I'm confuse?  I thought  if I log in in Metacity is the same, is not?  Could be possible that because Gnome-metacity have a different windows manager that  the last Gnome version ("Mutter") the extension never will be compatible?

Comment: @Aby Metacity was the window manager of Gnome 2, but is still used in Fallback mode.

Comment: I have to say before, Thanks all of you for the help and fast response.
@xangua, yes you are right and Mutter for Gnome 3, this mean that the extension in Gnome 3 will not be displayed in Metacity? (In the log in I have a gear with I can select between Gnome - Gnome classic - Gnome metacity and Gnome Flashback) and Only in Gnome (I think) I have extensions.